# How assign Pandas column value referring to list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

The idea is assign pandas column according to a list.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
time_window_order=['268','264','260','256','252','248','244','240']
df =DataFrame ({'time_window':['268','268','268','264','252','252','252','240'],'seq_no':[0,0,0,1,4,4,4,7]})

for idx,ord in enumerate(time_window_order):
    df.loc[df['time_window'].isin([ord]), 'centre_point'] = idx
```

But, I wonder whether there is more efficient or built-in pandas approach.

Comment: what do you mean column value referring to list. Do you want to store the index position of the list value  to `'centre_point'` column?

Comment: `centre_point` is will be the new column for the idx

Comment: You are looking to automate finding out the value of  `center_point` so it matches `seq_no` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list into a dictionary with the position as the value. The key will be the value in the list. Then do a [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to get the result.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
time_window_order=['268','264','260','256','252','248','244','240']
order_dict = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(time_window_order)}
df =DataFrame ({'time_window':['268','268','268','264','252','252','252','240'],'seq_no':[0,0,0,1,4,4,4,7]})
df['centre_point'] = df['time_window'].map(order_dict)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  time_window  seq_no  centre_point
0         268       0             0
1         268       0             0
2         268       0             0
3         264       1             1
4         252       4             4
5         252       4             4
6         252       4             4
7         240       7             7
```